# How to mark "current time" in calendar view and custom titles

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I've been amazed at the flexibility of [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) so far, but the following two elements have me stuck;

1. Is there any way to make the current time display in bold in the day view where it lists hours, without too much hackery?
2. Is there any way to change the title of the calendar element, so far it only takes on placeholder "variables" that are replaced with month names or similar, but I'd love the ability to specify my own header for them (This is easily done by adding it above the element, but if it's possible to add it within then why not, right?)

Comment: For #1, should time be bolded when viewing today only, or bolded regardless of day? Do you mean the "basic day" view, the "agenda day" view, or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For #1 Agenda DAY view I see this code

```
<tr class="fc-slot22 ">
  <th class="fc-agenda-axis fc-widget-header">11am</th>
  <td class="fc-widget-content"><div style="position:relative">&nbsp;</div></td>
</tr>
<tr class="fc-slot23 fc-minor">
  <th class="fc-agenda-axis fc-widget-header">&nbsp;</th>
  <td class="fc-widget-content"><div style="position:relative">&nbsp;</div></td>
</tr>
<tr class="fc-slot24 ">
   <th class="fc-agenda-axis fc-widget-header">12pm</th>
   <td class="fc-widget-content"><div style="position:relative">&nbsp;</div></td>
</tr>
```

so we need to look at THs:

```
var nowHours = new Date().getHours(); 
var hourAMPM = (nowHours>12)?(nowHours-12)+"pm":nowHours+"am";
if (nowHours===12) hourAMPM ="12pm";
$("th").removeClass("nowtime");
$("th").contains(hourAMPM).addClass("nowtime");
```

---

For #1 to bold calendar current DAY change

```
.fc-state-highlight {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFCC;
}
```

to

```
.fc-state-highlight {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFCC;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

For #2 you could change

```
<span class="fc-header-title">
<h2>April‌·2011</h2>
</span>
```

to whatever you want after creating the calendar

Comment: Indeed, I think that will be the way to do it, I just had a grain of hope there were some features for changing them that I was currently unaware of, thank you for the feedback!

Comment: @Strifariz Perhaps the author would be happy to look at that?